# Determine why a specific version of a package is getting download?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

Is there anyway to determine why a specific version of a package is getting downloaded by a solution when you do a package restore? Is not a direct reference rather package being used by something else we are referencing. I have cleared the package cache and restored & something is causing it to be downloaded. I have scoured the project but am unable to find that specific version of that package.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `obj/project.assets.json` (created during the restore).

It includes your full dependency graph, so you see everything that's pulling in the package